# Is it possible to use [maxSelectedLabels] property in an ngif condition?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng

I'm using Prime NG Multiselect component and I want to show selectedItemsLabel="{0} Selected" when there are more than 3 selected checkboxes, but if all of the checkboxes are selected, then selectedItemsLabel="All" should be shown in the placeholder.

I'm new to angular and I been following documentation of this [MultiSelect](https://primeng.org/multiselect) component, yet this doesn't show the options to able to implement multiple conditions of properties, and I was wondering if it's even possible.

Example of how It might be

```
 <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
                            <p-multiSelect
                                [ngModel]="value"
                                [options]="routeOptions"
                                placeholder="Any"
                                (onChange)="filter($event.value)"
                                optionLabel="name"
                                selectedItemsLabel="{0} selected"
                                [maxSelectedLabels]="3"
                            >
                                <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                                    <div>
                                        <span class="p-ml-1">{{ option.name }}</span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div *ngIf="[maxSelectedLabels="routeOptions.length - 1"] Then selectedItemsLabel="All"></div>
                                </ng-template>
                            </p-multiSelect>
                        </ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can. First give the component a ref with **#** like this:

```
<p-multiSelect
  #myMultiSelect
  [ngModel]="value"
  [options]="routeOptions"
  placeholder="Any"
  (onChange)="filter($event.value)"
  optionLabel="name"
  selectedItemsLabel="{0} selected"
  [maxSelectedLabels]="3"
  >
.......
```

Then you have access to it:

```
<div *ngIf="myMultiSelect.maxSelectedLabels === routeOptions.length - 1">Im visible</div>
```

If the option of `maxSelectedLables` is the length - 1 of routeOptions then the `div` is visible. That is how **ngIf works**

### BUT

Thats not what you want. You wanna set the `selectedItemsLabel` property. And you have it not understand correctly. You set the `maxSelectedLables` to 3 as example **AND** set the `selectedItemsLabel` directly, too! The text of the `selectedItemsLabel` will be only shown if needed (controlled by the component).

```
<h5>Basic</h5>
<p-multiSelect #meins [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" defaultLabel="Select a City" optionLabel="name"
  [maxSelectedLabels]="3" selectedItemsLabel="{0} items selected">
</p-multiSelect>
```

Look [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-multiselect-demo-pmk5sj?file=src/app/app.component.html) the Stackblitz!

The [documentation](https://primeng.org/multiselect) of `ng-prime` will helps, too and say:

> **selectedItemsLabel:**   Label to display after exceeding max selected labels e.g. ({0} items selected), defaults "ellipsis" keyword to indicate a text-overflow.

### UPDATE 18.02.2023

You wanna show "ALL" only if all items selected. So add the `onChange` event and **bind** the selectedItemsLabel. Why binding? It has some problems with a condition in it. So we make it inside the code.

**HTML**

```
<p-multiSelect [options]="cities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCities" defaultLabel="Select a City" optionLabel="name"
  [maxSelectedLabels]="2" [selectedItemsLabel]="bindTest" (onChange)="onChange()">
</p-multiSelect>
```

Inside the code do the follow with `onChange`:

**Code**

```
  onChange() {
    if (this.selectedCities.length === this.cities.length) {
      this.bindTest = "ALL";
      this.changeRef.detectChanges();
    }
     else {
       this.bindTest = "{0} items selected";   
       this.changeRef.detectChanges();
    }
  }
```

Now it works how you wish. One important thing: We use `changeRef.detectChanges();` Without this the components selected text will not changing directly. Import it in the components constructor:

```
  constructor(
    private countryService: CountryService,
    private primengConfig: PrimeNGConfig,
    private changeRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {
.....
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! however, then at the same time in a if condition setting selectedItemsLabel to "All" when everything is selected is not possible ?
Logic would be 
    If maxSelectedLabel="is from 3 to the total count of all possible routes -1" show selectedItemsLabel="{0} Selected"   Else if maxSelectedLabel="is all selected Routes" show selectedItemslabel="All"

Comment: You do not need to do this. But it is possible, in a other way. In some Hours I give you a updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, showing All when everything is selected is part of my business requirement as well as showing just the count of how many selected when you select more than 3 (till you select All)

Comment: My answer is updated. Now it show "all"

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks the clear button of p-columnFilter display="menu" property. Well, the clear still works, but the text box is not being depopulated

Comment: It works fine in my example... But I think that is a new question... So show a little code and I'll try to help you.

Comment: hey @Flo bellow I added a stackblitz and more description to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I made a Stackblitz of the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-tablefilter-demo-ipt7y1?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

*(Expand the page to the left to view the column filter in the stackblitz)*

If you notice, the clear button doesn't clear the selected textbox anymore. After some testing it seems the [(ngModel)] breaks it, I think it got to do something with two-way binding? It is not shown in the stackblitz, but if you include

```
(onChange)="filter($event.value)"
```

the clear button still **clears the filter from** the table, but not in the selected textbox.

I found out that there is this property

```
[showClear]="true"
```

That adds an X at the end of the textbox that clears it out. Sadly, the styling/positioning is not what I need.

What could be the ways to fix the clear button ? Add a ts function to clear out the selected values? If so, how to bind it to the clear button because it is generated from

```
<p-columnFilter
          display="menu"
```

menu property and I had no luck to find the way to try add/change functionality to that button.